# Autotrading disabled by client when running python script for metatrader5

Tags: python, automation, algorithmic-trading, metatrader5

when trying to send an order to  metatrader 5 using python i receive an OrderSendResult saying "Autotrading disabled by client". How can i fix it

I turned on "Allow algorithmic trading" in the Tools > options section but still getting same results.